# Lump on Goldfish

Tags: aquarium, diseases, goldfish

Several months ago my red cap oranda developed a lump on his side. It resembled an acne nodule. The lump was beneath his scales and didn't seem to cause him any trouble. He had some mild red streaking in his tail which cleared up once I began doing more frequent water changes.

Recently, the lump has swollen. In fact, it looks like there are two smaller lumps beside it. The scales are pushed up and the area is red. See photos below.

Today the lump ruptured and briefly suppurated a stringy white tissue. Despite the lump and the rupture, the goldfish is behaving normally.

At first I suspected this was a tumor, but the rupture has me thinking otherwise. Can anyone with experienced help me diagnose the problem and advise me how to resolve it?

**Tank Specs:**

- size: 35 gallons
- fish: 1 red cap oranda; 1 black telescope
- food: flakes/peas
- nitrate: 20 ppm
- nitrite: 0 ppm
- hardness: 150 ppm
- chlorine: 0 ppm
- alkalinity: 80 ppm
- pH 7.2
- ammonia: between 0-0.25 ppm (I use the API test kit which isn't super accurate.)

**Action Taken:**

I've already done a five day treatment on the tank using Marineland's All-In-One Remedy, since I've had luck with this product in the past. I'm also doing 1/3 tank partial  water changes every other day in an effort to keep the water pristine.

**Photos:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

(I'll update the photos if I can get some better ones.)

Comment: Did your fish recover? No answers in 3 years?
My red cap Oranda has a very similar lump beneath its eye: a red lump with a white streak through it. The fish was sitting on the substrate for most of the day, but its dorsal fin stayed erect. Both eyes were swollen and bulging. I started feeding it peas only, and today the lump and red area is much smaller and the fish is now moving around the tank, mostly normally. Occasionally it rubs the lump against a plant. I’m thinking it’s some type of parasite. I have a UV steriliser operating, which will hopefully protect the remaining fish.

Comment: @Glenn Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. I converted your answer to a comment since this site requires every answer to actually answer the question. Just a side note to make sure: carefully read the instructions to the UV sterializer. It can not only damage parasites and bacteria, but also the eyes and skin of your fish, if directed at the aquarium.